# threejs OBJMTLLoader object with children: children objects doesn't have position / rotation

Tags: rotation, position, three.js, children

I don't know if it is a bug: I can't find nothing simillar on github bug/issue tracking or stackoverflow either.

The problem is that when I import an object with children objects with OBJMTLloader, the position and rotation appears to be set to 0 on the children.

The parent object has correct positioning data.

I assume this is not the correct behaviour. How I can know the position of every children of the object?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the limitation of the OBJ format itself:

http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/114389

Try using Collada or GLtF instead.